# How to get a good web reader for iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, browserify

Given a webpage, I would like to extract the text for a reader view. I am aware that `SFSafariViewController` offers a reader mode, but for my application, I need the actual text string. I am also aware of the [Mercury parser](https://mercury.postlight.com/web-parser/), but I prefer a solution that runs locally.

I have tried many options:

- [DZReadability](https://github.com/DZamataev/DZReadability) (it works but the output is oftentimes not very good, much worse than the reader of Safari)
- [Mozilla Readability](https://github.com/mozilla/readability) (I could not make it run under iOS)
- [luin/Readability](https://github.com/luin/readability) (I tried very hard but I could not make it work under iOS)

`luin/Readability` looks very interesting. It seems to be a very active Github project. However, I could not make it work under iOS. What I tried/did:

I installed and used `browserify` to get a stand-alone JavaScript file. However, I got an error message `Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module`. I read that this problem may be solved by using `derequire`. I tried it but did not succeed.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to make luin/Readability work on iOS, possibly by using `browserify` or in any other way?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem in my project that needed to render HTML from Readability as TextView. My initial approach was rendering using `WKWebView` by injecting slightly modified Mozilla Readability using `evaluateJavaScript` of `WKWebView`.

Mozilla Readability code was stored as local file and was modified by appending the following code:

```
// Execute Readbility on the currently loaded DOM

var uri = {
spec: location.href,
host: location.host,
prePath: location.protocol + "//" + location.host,
scheme: location.protocol.substr(0, location.protocol.indexOf(":")),
pathBase: location.protocol + "//" + location.host +  location.pathname.substr(0, location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
}; var documentClone = document.cloneNode(true); var article = new Readability(uri, documentClone).parse(); article;
```

The resulting content is then rendered using `DTCoreText`. `WKWebView` will load all resources of the webpage including all images, ads etc. This makes the approach very memory intensive, I tried circumventing this by parsing and removing images before passing it to `WKWebView`. Overall this works, but depending on your use case might not be very elegant or fast.

Currently I'm using a different approach, which involves running luis Readability on a server using phantomJS, which gives better results in terms of content extraction and is much less memory intensive on the client.